# How can I declare and populate a collection at the same time?

Tags: c#

I am trying the following:

```
    public class ResultDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    }

List<ResultDTO> result1 = new List<ResultDTO> () {
   new ResultDTO () { Id:1, Text: "abc", AnswerId: "1", AnswerText: "Aab1" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id:1, Text: "abc", AnswerId: "2", AnswerText: "Aab2" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id:1, Text: "abc", AnswerId: "3", AnswerText: "Aab3" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id:1, Text: "def", AnswerId: "4", AnswerText: "Aab4" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id:1, Text: "def", AnswerId: "5", AnswerText: "Aab5" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id:1, Text: "def", AnswerId: "6", AnswerText: "Aab6" }
}
```

This gives me many syntax errors in the IDE.  Can someone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Change `:` to `=`.

Comment: If you want, you can even leave out the empty parenthesis `()` when you call the zero-parameter constructor and use collection initializer or object initializer syntax, so `new Xxx { ..., ..., ... }` is short for `new Xxx() { ..., ..., ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not JSon object and array. the property can be assigned using `=` operator.

```
List<ResultDTO> result1 = new List<ResultDTO> () {
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", AnswerId= 1, AnswerText= "Aab1" },
   ....
}
```

I would like to suggest you to create constructor which is having parameters for properties;

```
public class ResultDTO
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }

    public ResultDTO(int id, string _text, int ansId, string ansText)
    {
        Id=id;
        Text = _text;
        AnswerId = ansId;
        AnswerText = ansText;
    }
}
```

then initialize the list like this.

```
List<ResultDTO> result1 = new List<ResultDTO> () {
   new ResultDTO (1,"abc",1,"Aab1"),
   new ResultDTO (1,"abc",2,"Aab2"),
   new ResultDTO (1,"abc",3,"Aab3"),
   ....
}
```

This will give you some advantage when you specify the property readonly. Look at the above class I have declared `Id` property publicly readable and cannot be set out of the class.

Answer (score 2):

When initializing a class you need to use = instead of :

```
    public class ResultDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    }

List<ResultDTO> result1 = new List<ResultDTO> () {
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", AnswerId= 1, AnswerText= "Aab1" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", AnswerId= 2, AnswerText= "Aab2" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", AnswerId= 3, AnswerText= "Aab3" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", AnswerId= 4, AnswerText= "Aab4" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", AnswerId= 5, AnswerText= "Aab5" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", AnswerId= 6, AnswerText= "Aab6" }
}
```